# Conditionally add class to specific elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I am trying to write an if statement to check if the html of an LI element matches a variable, and if it does, adding a class to that specific li.

My HTML:

```
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
<li>Four</li>
```

What I've tried so far:

```
var x = "Three";
if($('li').html() == x) {
  $(this).addClass("active");
}
```

Desired result:

```
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li class="active">Three</li>
<li>Four</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the responses everyone, I really appreciate it! using .filter() works great, although I'm sure the .each() function that @Adrift posted would work as well. Wish I could accept more than one answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would want to use the filter method:

```
var x = "Three";
$( "li" ).filter(function( index ) {

   return $(this).html() == x;
}).addClass("active");
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, working great, thanks!!

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `.each()`

```
var x = "Three";
$('li').each(function() {
    if($(this).html() == x) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JVQ5A/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `filter` method :

```
var x = "Three";
$('li').filter(function(){
    return $.trim(this.innerHTML) == x;
}).addClass('active')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way -

```
var x = "Three";
$('li').each(function() {
    if( $(this).is(':contains("' + x + '")')) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/maju/M73nU/1/)

```
var x = "Three";
$('li').each(function(i,elem){
    if($(elem).text() == x) {
      $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});
```